# GAE Datastore performance vs SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm seeing terrible performance using the GAE datastore on both the dev server and the production server. I have the following simplified model:

```
class Team(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    # + 1 other property
    # home_games from Game
    # away_games from Game

class Game(db.Model):
    date = db.DateProperty()
    year = db.IntegerProperty()
    home_team = db.ReferenceProperty(Team, collection_name='home_games')
    away_team = db.ReferenceProperty(Team, collection_name='away_games')
    # + 4 other properties
    # results from TeamResults

class TeamResults(db.Model):
    game = db.ReferenceProperty(Game, collection_name='results')
    location = db.StringProperty(choices=('home', 'away'))
    score = db.IntegerProperty()
    # + 17 other properties
```

I only have one index, on Game year and date. Inserting a small dataset of 478 teams and 786 games took about 50 seconds. A simple query:

```
games = Game.all()
games.filter('year = ', 2000)
games.order('date')

for game in games:
    for result in game.results:
        # do something with the result
```

took about 45 seconds.

I'm moving from SQLite-based data storage, and the above query on a much larger dataset takes a fraction of a second. Is my data just modeled poorly? Is Datastore just this slow?

**Edit 1**
To give a little more background, I'm inserting data from a user-uploaded file. The file is uploaded into the blobstore, then I use csv.reader to parse it. This happens periodically, and queries are run based on cron jobs.

Comment: If you pushed the date from the game down into the team results, then you could actually just fetch all of the game results matching your date range.  This would make your code run a lot faster.  Unless of course you need to update the other entities.  (Still worth a try and precaching other things like Teams etc.. would also help)

Comment: doing a bottom up query and prefetching reference properties for result sets could really be a win.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is that you insert these records one by one

you need to use batch inserts, see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata

Or you may want to insert list of records, as described in documentation:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Batch_Operations

Comment: I'm inserting data from a user-uploaded file. The file is uploaded into the blobstore, then I use csv.reader to parse it. The bulk uploader doesn't look like it will work for that.

Comment: I had to restructure the model a little, but between that, using memcache for Team keys, and using batch inserts, I've gotten much more reasonable performance.

Comment: Also consider making some properties unindexed if you don't need to query on them. Each indexed property is an extra write op when you write the entity. Finally, performance of the dev_appserver is awful -- I hope you reported the times you got when your app was deployed.

Comment: @GuidovanRossum Adding indexed=False where possible made a big difference, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any evidence that you're using `indexed=False` on any of your properties. Each such property will take two additional writes (one for the ascending index, one for the descending one) per write. Those add up quickly.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't using indexed=False. Adding it where possible made a big difference, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the bulk loader, because you already uploaded the CSV. But you can use batch insert. 
See these tips: http://googleappengine.blogspot.nl/2009/06/10-things-you-probably-didnt-know-about.html
Look for : 5. You can batch put, get and delete operations for efficiency